# Modal popup not working after clearing browser cache

Tags: magento2, popup, modal

I am using the bootstrap modal popup to show some content on site on click. First time when I click a link the modal popup works fine, but when I clear my browser cache and click on again on the same link the modal popup does not work.

It only shows the black background.

Comment: did you get any errors in console? would be great if you can share screenshot.

Comment: There is no such error, it works after a refresh but when I clear the browser cache it does not work.

Comment: Without code review it can't be solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. open in incognito window magento clean/flush cache and static
2. content deploy. click inspect element in browser - set as
3. display:block in css edit block. try another browser.
4. If all do not help you, look at your code, mb you have an error. Why it is working before? Because css cached as well by browser and magento.

After that run below command line:

```
 php bin/magento cache:flush 
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento setup:static-content deploy -f en_US
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I don't think its a CSS issue. "in" class for modal is not being added when I click on the link for the first time after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Without code i can't help you to fix it